# RcppArrayFire passing a matrix row as af::array input

Tags: rcpp, arrayfire

In this simple example I would like to subset a matrix by row and pass it to another cpp function; the example demonstrates this works by passing an input array to the other function first.

```
#include "RcppArrayFire.h"

using namespace Rcpp;

af::array theta_check_cpp( af::array theta){

  if(*theta(1).host<double>() >= 1){
    theta(1) = 0;
  }

  return theta;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
af::array theta_check(RcppArrayFire::typed_array<f64> theta){

  const int theta_size = theta.dims()[0];

  af::array X(2, theta_size);
  X(0,  af::seq(theta_size)) = theta_check_cpp( theta );
  X(1,  af::seq(theta_size)) = theta;
  // return X;
  Rcpp::Rcout << " works till here";
  return theta_check_cpp( X.row(1) );
}


/*** R
theta <- c( 2, 2, 2)
theta_check(theta)
*/
```

Comment: What is your question? What is the error or obstacle you are hitting?

Comment: the specific error is "Requested type doesn't match with array
In function double *af::array::host() const"

Comment: I am rather confused because my other functions take a subset of an af:array that is a row vector just fine.  The other confusing bit is that the second function accepts the input as an af::array but errors on output, even if there is no body to the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [constructor](http://arrayfire.org/docs/group__construct__mat.htm#ga1f0b51e20111680c7fe3c74d54c982dd) you are using to create `X` has an argument `ty` for the data type, which defaults to `f32`. Therefore `X` uses 32 bit floats and you cannot extract a 64 bit host pointer from that. Either use

```
af::array X(2, theta_size, f64);
```

to create an array using 64 bit doubles, or extract a 32 bit host pointer via

```
if(*theta(1).host<float>() >= 1){
   ...
```